# Dynamically referencing a Service using Felix annotations

Tags: reference, annotations, osgi, apache-felix

I have created an interface which two different services are implementing.

Consider interface is named as CheckReference and two different classes CheckReferenceImpl1 and CheckReferencImpl2 are implementing it.

```
@Component 
@Service(value = CheckReference.class) 
@Property(name = "domain", value = "ref1") 
public class CheckReferenceImpl1 implements CheckReference
```

And another one,

```
@Component 
@Service(value = CheckReference.class) 
@Property(name = "domain", value = "ref2") 
public class CheckReferenceImpl2 implements CheckReference
```

Now I want to dynamically load the implementation depending on my need using @Reference annotation dynamically. 
So , In a check condition

```
public class LoadReference { 
    @Reference 
    CheckReference checkReference 

    if(check) { 
      // load checkReferencImpl1 
    } else { 
       // load checkReferenceImpl2 
    } 
}
```

Also I know that I can use target property to load specific implemenation. But that is static way. 
But in order to do this dynamically , Not able to relate from specifications and tutorials how should I do this ??

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make `LoadReference` a `@Component`, so that it is managed by the SCR (otherwise `@Reference` won't work either). Next, you have to provide a configuration for it using the Configuration Admin Service. In this configuration, you can provide a filter for the reference by providing a property with the name `REFERENCE_NAME.target`:

```
checkReference.target = FILTER_EXPRESSION
```

`FILTER_EXPRESSION` is a standard LDAP-expression used in OSGi-filters. Due to property propagation, this configuration property will be propagated to the service-component, and it will be used when selecting a target service for `checkReference`. This does not require any code for checking the condition in `LoadReference`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [ComponentContext.locateService](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/ComponentContext.html#locateService%28java.lang.String%29)?